# Is the Raspberry Pi a good teaching tool for students learning assembler?

Tags: education, teaching, arm, assembler

When I took an assembler course, we used a NIOS II Altera board which had a display, some LED lights and programmable buttons. One of the more useful exercises was to write a binary calculator using the LEDs' and the buttons. So, here's my questions:

- Is there something similar (or a good substitute) that you can plug
  into the raspberry pi?
- Is there some obvious downside to using the Raspberry Pi that I
  haven't thought of (maybe ARM assembly isn't a good way to learn)?
- Is there perhaps something else that the instruction set manual
  will allow us to do that could give some *visual effects* on the Pi?

Comment: Interesting question, but it is quite subjective. I would say that learning any assembly language is educational.

Comment: @Jivings I'm too much of a beginner to realise how subjective that might be :) But the LED/Button part is concrete :p

Comment: The first part is a request for product recommendation (off-topic.)  The second part is subjective, as is the title.  VTC.  The third question is a good one though - maybe it can be rewritten as "How can the LEDs on the RasPi PCB be manipulated in software?"

Comment: @finnw I meant objective downsides, which do exist :p and the first part is Indeed a product request, but it's also a matter of compatibility.

Comment: I think you should design a calculator board. It should only take a few quid to produce and would be a fantastic educational tool!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain You mean making the Raspberry Pi a calculator using assembly and a GPIO with leds/displays? That's what I was hoping for. If you mean anything else, I'm interested, but not qualified :p

Comment: I mean producing an expansion board with an LCD and calculator buttons. The task would be to make it a calculator, using assembly.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Yup I'll definitely try to accomplish that. It will take some time though (for starters, I don't have my Pi yet). If I ever get it done I'll report it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not solving all your problems, but you can use GPIO to activate LEDs and recieve input from buttons.

There is a good video about using GPIO [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_NvDTZIaS4&feature=player_embedded), and a google search should help.

You could try getting a breadboard [here](http://www.maplin.co.uk/ad-100-breadboard-5195) (very cheap!), or again, google will do no end of good.

I actually have [these](http://www.kemo-electronic.de/en/Light-Sound/LED/S093-LED-creative-set.php) [two](http://www.kemo-electronic.de/en/Light-Sound/LED/S036-Light-emitting-diodes-approx-30-pieces.php) LED kits, which are nice for their variation of different LEDs, but there's such a range of LEDs that it really depends on what you are looking for.

Push-to-make switches are a little harder to come across, but you can find some [here](http://www.maplin.co.uk/black-push-to-break-bulk-pack-634672) for example.

Comment: Anybody going to give me advice as to why they downvoted? (I just want to make my answer better.)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, or misinterpreted my level of expertise :p I know such boards exist, I just have no idea what fits both the Pi and my purpose. That GPIO board looks great though (especially since it's mentioned on the official site), thanks for the links! +1

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted so I don't know if this is why, but from what I understand it is generally considered bad form to tell the OP to google the answer in a Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: I said that mainly because at that point in the answer, I was just googling and then typing what I googled. As an answerer, I reckon I should use the knowledge/skills I have that the OP *doesn't* (Keyser, this is what I got wrong :) ). You have a a good point though.

Comment: @ACarter I downvoted because of the Googling - sorry I didn't comment earlier. If you remove the phrases telling the OP to Google and perhaps add some more hard links in its place, I'd be happy to remove the downvote.

Comment: @berry, I have improved it, but it's your choice if you remove the downvote, I see exactly why you did it, and it's your choice.

Comment: Coh, the voting on this question is doing my head in... (yes please explain, I just want to make it better.)

Comment: Thanks for the "undownvote" as it seems to be called, whoever that was.